# Data analytics in road transportation

Tags: data-analysis

What kind of insights can we give from point A to point B transactions. A and B are two places, All I can think of is about descriptive statistics like how many transactions from A and what is count of transactions between places and all.

Comment: do you have timing information when the transaction occur?

Comment: Yes i have date of transaction, can i do something with date time and material moved/vehicle used?

Comment: how many different A's and B's are there?

Comment: around 50k but 700 unique routes. like if A is Pune and B is Nagpur then the same A and B for different prices and different times 300 times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the tools from **Network Science** (1) to model (A,B) as edges in a network. Since you have timing information on the transactions you can reconstruct paths on that network.

Using **statistical network analysis** you can find for example which points A from your dataset (or nodes in the network) are of importance, as in how many routes lead to that point. For this you'd study a **centrality measure** (degree centrality, closeness centrality, betweenness centrality, etc.) (2)

Or you can find which points are close together in terms of transactions between them, for this you'd look for **community detection** or **clustering**. (2)

You can also look at the timing data, to calculate the intra- and inter- transaction time distributions.

(1): Barabási, A. L. (2016). Network science. Cambridge university press.

(2): [Salter‐Townshend, M., White, A., Gollini, I., & Murphy, T. B. (2012). Review of statistical network analysis: models, algorithms, and software. Statistical Analysis and Data Mining: The ASA Data Science Journal, 5(4), 243-264.](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1002/sam.11146)